# Как класс может использоваться в коде без создания экземпляра этого класса?

Tags: c++

в самоучителе говорилось, что невозможно в коде использовать сам класс пока не создашь экземпляр и уже этот экземпляр надо использовать

вот немного кода:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LessThan{
public:
    int operator()(int x, int y){
        return x < y;
    }
};

int main(){
    LessThan b;

    cout << b(2, 3) << endl;
    cout << LessThan()(2, 3) << endl; // ! почему нет ошибки?

    return 0;
}
```

в чем секрет?

Comment: И все же это не совсем верное утверждение. По крайней мере класс (имя класса) можно использовать в sizeof()

Comment: @avp И статические методы можно вызывать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы понять "секрет" достаточно пристально взглянуть на этот код:

```
LessThan()(2, 3)
```

Что здесь происходит? `LessThan` - это класс, следовательно, круглые скобки - вызов конструктора без параметров. Конструктор в классе не объявлен, но согласно стандарту он будет сгенерирован компилятором автоматически. Такой автоматический конструктор по умолчанию всегда создаётся, если программист не определил ни одного конструктора, либо явно не запретил автогенерацию. Конструктор создаёт экземпляр и возвращает ссылку на этот экземпляр. Далее у экземпляра вызывается перегруженный `operator()`, который выполняет сравнение и возвращает результат этого сравнения.

Но у созданного экземпляра нет имени. Это так называемый *анонимный временный объект*. Он существует только до тех пор, пока используется. Как только его использование прекращено, он разрушается. Таким образом, после выполнения сравнения объект исчезнет из памяти.

P.S. Не уверен, что анонимный временный объект будет разрушен *сразу* после завершения использования. Может быть, просуществует до точки с запятой. Надеюсь, более глубоко знающие стандарт люди прояснят этот вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Создается временный (анонимный) экземпляр класса LessThan, используется его метод (оператор ()), экземпляр удаляется. Никакой магии.